# separating viewroute.js file from angularjs does not load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, modularity

I am able to run this code without separating. But when I seperate it ceases to run without any error on console. Also in separate viewroute.js I am able to hit debugger but not able to load normal behavior. I am doing some conceptual error as I am facing issues in separating services from same code as well. Please advise. Tried loading jquery before angularjs as well

By Default localhost address is :- http://localhost:3000/#!/

folder structure is as follows:-
public> 1. controllers>1. membershipcontroller
2. mgRoute > viewroute.js
views- index.html

Index.html file is as follows, this contains order of scripts being loaded:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tdmModule">

<head>
    <title>welcome</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular- 
        route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular- 
          resource.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ngRoute/viewroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="controllers/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <div class="container pt-5">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My app.js file is as follows:-

```
var app = angular.module("tdmModule", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(['$qProvider', function($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

//I WANT TO SEPERATE THIS FILE FROM HERE TO A SEPERATE FILE
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "home",
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .when("/membershipdetails", {
                templateUrl: "membershipdetails",
                controller: 'membershipController'
            })
            .when("/help", {
                templateUrl: "help",
                controller: 'helpController'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
]);
// TILL HERE 

app.controller('membershipController', function($scope, $filter, $http,
    $httpParamSerializer, $location, membershipService, setnotanoption,
    compileservice) {
    var absurl = $location.absUrl().split('/#!/')[1];
    $scope.pagename = absurl;
    $scope.noOfColumn = false;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 5;
    $scope.q = '';
    $scope.selectColumnList = [];
    $scope.tableBody = [];
    $scope.columnResponse = [];
    $scope.output = [];
    $scope.inputjson = '';
    $scope.NoOfRecords = '';
    $scope.enviornmentOptions = [{
        name: "Select a Enviornment",
        id: 1
    }, {
        name: "BOSSBR03",
        id: 2
    }, {
        name: "BOSST03",
        id: 3
    }];

    $scope.selectedEnvOption = $scope.enviornmentOptions[0];

    $scope.nextData = function() {
        return $filter('filter')($scope.tableBody, $scope.q)
    }

    $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
        return Math.ceil($scope.nextData().length / $scope.pageSize);
    }


    $scope.isObjectEmpty = function(card) {
        return Object.keys(card).length === 0;
    }

    $('#fetchDetail').on('click', function() {
        $scope.selectColumnList = [];
        $("#rightColumn option").each(function(index) {
            $scope.selectColumnList[index] = $(this).text();
        });
        if ($scope.selectColumnList.length > 3) {
            $("#columnSelectionModel").modal('hide');
        } else {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.noOfColumn = true;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What I tried is the following file:- viewroute.js.
I am able to hit debugger that implies it is being loaded. but when i comment it out from app.js file. My page does not get loaded. Doesn't throw an error as well in console.

```
var app = angular.module("tdmModule", ["ngRoute"]);

//for Possibly unhandled rejection
app.config(['$qProvider', function($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

debugger; ///this debugger is being hit
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "home",
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when("/membershipdetails", {
            templateUrl: "membershipdetails",
            controller: 'membershipController'
        })
        .when("/help", {
            templateUrl: "help",
            controller: 'helpController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are declaring the **tdmModule** twice.

You can follow two path:

1. Declaring your routes as **part of the tdmModule**

   In this way your `viewroutes.js` will looks like:

   ```
   var app = angular.module("tdmModule");

   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when("/", {
           templateUrl: "home",
           controller: 'homeController'
       })
       .when("/membershipdetails", {
           templateUrl: "membershipdetails",
           controller: 'membershipController'
       })
       .when("/help", {
           templateUrl: "help",
           controller: 'helpController'
       })
       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
       });
   });
   ```
2. Declaring your routes as **part of a new module**, a *routesModule*, as dependency of your **tdmModule**.

   In this way your `viewroutes.js` will looks like:

   ```
   var app = angular.module("routesModule", ["ngRoute"]);

   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when("/", {
           templateUrl: "home",
           controller: 'homeController'
       })
       .when("/membershipdetails", {
           templateUrl: "membershipdetails",
           controller: 'membershipController'
       })
       .when("/help", {
           templateUrl: "help",
           controller: 'helpController'
       })
       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
       });
   });
   ```

   And your `app.js` should be:

   ```
   var app = angular.module("tdmModule", ["routesModule"]);
   ...
   ```

Hope it helps.

---

**Edited**

First option doesn't work in your case because of the **order of your scripts**.

Order is important, you have to declare the **tdmModule** before defining a config on it.

So you have to place `controller/app.js` import before `viewroutes.js`.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. It worked(2nd way) but I still wonder why doesn't 1st one works